# Sound on all apps is slow when played through a USB soundcard

Tags: sound, usb, firefox, pulseaudio, rhythmbox

I have been using an external DAC (USB) to play music through my amp. For over a year it has worked brilliantly, then a week ago it has started playing everything slowly (about 10% slow) it even plays live radio slowly???? Same regardless whether Rhythmbox, Firefox or Chrome. I run a Lenovo T420 and Ubuntu 20.04. Any ideas? I have looked through dozens of threads and they at best half address my problem - download Pulse Audio (hasn't worked) etc

Comment: Test the DAC on another computer to see if it is the DAC or the computer.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't have access to another computer. It isn't impossible that I can find someone to lend me their laptop (really not easy) - or I can find an adapter and maybe run my Android phone through it, 

For context - the live radio itself runs slowly on Firefox/Chrome and Rhythmbox runs equally slowly  If I set a stopwatch and play one minute of live radio or one minute on Rhythmbox, according to their timer they have only played 51 or 52 seconds; my sound AND source are actually running slower when played through the DAC.

Comment: or boot into windows or a ubuntu live usb

Comment: thanks, I have a live USB I can use, I will do that

Comment: So just launched Ubuntu via a live USB and the audio works fine. There is nothing wrong with my DAC/External soundcard. 

So ... any ideas? Anything I can un-install/re-install?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was an update during March that (for some magic reason) changed the default-sample-rate of the sound card (I was facing the same issue).

I had tried whatever app/solution I found online but apparently the solutions is:

a) open the configuration of `pulse` by running:

```
sudo vi /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

b) find the line concerning `default-sample-rate`. It should start with a `;` meaning that its commented out. Remove the `;` and adjust the sample rate to your needs. For me `48000` did the trick:

```
default-sample-rate = 48000
```

c) Restart `pulseaudio` by executing:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

That should make everything back to normal

Comment: thanks Nikos, I don't have Pulse though, just ALSA. Any workaround you know about? I have looked in the software centre for Pulse and I get nothing

Comment: Just checked via terminal - I do have pulseaudio. Thanks Nikos I will give that a go now

Comment: Hi, I can delete the ; and the 44100 but I cannot add anything to the config file - any ideas?

Comment: So .. I have had to hard shut down Terminal a few times. It shows that there is a pulse audio process that is ongoing - it does not allow editing other than deleting and it does not allow me to kill any processes so i have to hard shut terminal to escape it. To be honest I have been going round in circles for a couple of weeks now - thanks Nikos for your help but I am going to have to re-install Ubuntu again I think, for the second time this year already. I really really don't want to.

Comment: This is what I get when I run the sudo vi /etc/pulse/daemon.conf command
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "/etc/pulse/.daemon.conf.swp"
          owned by: root   dated: Thu Apr 07 13:20:35 2022
         file name: /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
          modified: YES
         user name: root   host name: kelvin-ThinkPad-T420
        process ID: 8505
While opening file "/etc/pulse/daemon.conf"
             dated: Wed Jul 15 10:52:36 2020

Comment: Try to login with your root account by running: `sudo su` and then provide your password.
Try then to edit the file again and dont forget to save when exiting
Then restart the pulseaudio with the command I provided on step (c)